# Is there a way to print an Armadillo matrix in gdb?

Tags: c++, debugging, matrix, gdb, armadillo

I'm using gdb to debug my c++ program.
I'm using the armadillo numerical library to define my matrices. I have an armadillo matrix defined like so:

```
mat A = randu<mat>(5,5);
```

Is it possible to print the whole matrix while using the gdb debugger?

Comment: Recent gdb (latest release is GDB 7.4) can be scripted in Python. Did you consider it??

Answer (score 10):

The question may be old, but stumbling over it made me find a solution for my own work.

Due to the template-based nature of the Armadillo library you need to provide some helpers of your own:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

template<class Matrix>
void print_matrix(Matrix matrix) {
    matrix.print(std::cout);
}

//provide explicit instantiations of the template function for 
//every matrix type you use somewhere in your program.
template void print_matrix<arma::mat>(arma::mat matrix);
template void print_matrix<arma::cx_mat>(arma::cx_mat matrix);

int main() {
    arma::mat matrix = arma::randu(10,10);

    return 0;
}
```

Now you can easily call `print_matrix` from within `gdb`:

```
(gdb) call print_matrix<arma::Mat<double> >(matrix) 
   0.8402   0.4774   0.0163   0.5129   0.5267   0.5260   0.2383   0.5316   0.6879   0.9565
   0.3944   0.6289   0.2429   0.8391   0.7699   0.0861   0.9706   0.0393   0.1660   0.5886
   0.7831   0.3648   0.1372   0.6126   0.4002   0.1922   0.9022   0.4376   0.4401   0.6573
   0.7984   0.5134   0.8042   0.2960   0.8915   0.6632   0.8509   0.9318   0.8801   0.8587
   0.9116   0.9522   0.1567   0.6376   0.2833   0.8902   0.2667   0.9308   0.8292   0.4396
   0.1976   0.9162   0.4009   0.5243   0.3525   0.3489   0.5398   0.7210   0.3303   0.9240
   0.3352   0.6357   0.1298   0.4936   0.8077   0.0642   0.3752   0.2843   0.2290   0.3984
   0.7682   0.7173   0.1088   0.9728   0.9190   0.0200   0.7602   0.7385   0.8934   0.8148
   0.2778   0.1416   0.9989   0.2925   0.0698   0.4577   0.5125   0.6400   0.3504   0.6842
   0.5540   0.6070   0.2183   0.7714   0.9493   0.0631   0.6677   0.3540   0.6867   0.9110
```

Thanks to tab completion you only need to actually type a few characters of `print_matrix<arma::Mat<double> >`.

Comment: +1. This must be the most elegant way to pretty print armadillo matrices. However, executing the command "-exec call print_matrix<arma::Mat<double> >(matrix)" in VS Code Debug Console crashes my debugging session with error message: "Error: GDB exited unexpectedly. ERROR: GDB exited unexpectedly. Debugging will now abort." I think I miss one small piece of the puzzle to get there. Any idead from anyone? I'd highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to print directly in `gdb`, unfortunately no fancy format

```
> print *A.mem@5@5
$1 = {{0.84018771715470952, 0.39438292681909304,0.78309922375860586,0.79844003347607329, 0.91164735793678431},
{0.19755136929338396, 0.33522275571488902, 0.768229594811904, 0.27777471080318777, 0.55396995579543051}, 
{0.47739705186216025, 0.62887092476192441, 0.36478447279184334, 0.51340091019561551, 0.95222972517471283}, 
{0.91619506800370065, 0.63571172795990094, 0.71729692943268308, 0.14160255535580338, 0.60696887625705864}, 
{0.016300571624329581, 0.24288677062973696, 0.13723157678601872, 0.80417675422699042, 0.15667908925408455}}
```

Comment: @RolenClaes +1. Great! No fluff solution. Bit hard to read the output though, but requires no setup, or whatsoever. Just works out of the box! Thanks.

Comment: @RolenClaes I wonder if there are improved solutions since 2017.

Comment: @rawpointer Not that I know regarding GDB-improvments but you may always use pretty-printing, see  http://sigpack.sourceforge.net/md_2-build.html

Comment: @RolenClaes Ok, I see. Thanks for the answer and link.

Comment: Not working for me in CLion with gdb on Linux; gdb complains `No symbol operator* in current context`; not built with optimisation (`-g -O0`), `make` is verbose. gdb version 10.

Answer (score 4):

The best option is using gdb's python API to create [pretty printers](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html) for the armadillo classes. It works better than calling a C/C++ function, since it is always accessible (even when debugging from a core file where there is no program running). Furthermore, there is no risk of the linker discarding the function when it is not used in your program (thus making it unavailable when you are debugging in gdb).

The pretty printer code is loaded (sourced) from the `.gdbinit` file in your home folder. It will work in gdb running in a terminal as well as from an IDE (assuming the IDE does not avoid loading the `.gdbinit` file).

As an example, suppose you have the following two matrices

```cpp
arma::mat m1{{1.1, 2.2,  3},
             {  4,   5,  6}, 
             {  7,   8,  9},
             { 10,  11, 12},
             { 13,  14, 15},
             { 16,  17, 18}};

arma::cx_mat m2{{1.1 - 1.1j, 2.2 - 7.7j, 3},
                {         4,          5, 6},
                {         7,          8, 9},
                {         10,        11, 12},
                {         13,        14, 15},
                {         16,        17, 18}};
```

A pretty printer might shown them as

[image: m1]

[image: m2]

Notice how the complex matrix `m2` has its elements displayed both in rectangular form as well as in polar form (displaying the polar form can be disabled). This also works better with the rest of gdb. For instance, gdb allows you to the maximum number of elements to show in an array. The pretty printer will respect that if it is implemented to display the elements as standard arrays in gdb.

---

This is how the `m1` and `m2` matrices are displayed in CLion.

[image: m1 in CLion]

[image: m2 in CLion]

---

This pretty printer can be obtained from [here](https://github.com/darcamo/gdb_armadillo_helpers). There are a few other things such as some [xmethods](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-an-Xmethod.html) (python re-implementation of some C++ methods) and conversion to numpy arrays.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of these pretty printers.

Comment: If no one was bothered leaving comment here I come; this I can confirm that Linux system gdb version 10 with this works like a charm. Only thing needed was to clone the repo and two lines in `.gdbinit` under `$HOME`

Answer (score 2):

You can call C functions in `gdb`, so you just need a function that prints your objects. E.g:

```
(gdb) call printf("%.2f", 3.1428)
$7 = 4
(gdb) call fflush(stdout)
3.14$8 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

**For those using QtCreator**, you can inspect the values from your IDE by [extending GDB with Python Debugging Helpers](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html#extending-gdb-and-lldb-debugging-helpers) (maybe other IDEs support this feature too).

Place the following script in, for example, `~/debugHelpers.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import gdb      # gdb.Value()
import dumper   # dumper.Children()

def qdump__arma__Mat(d, value):
    array = value["mem"]
    cols = value["n_cols"]
    rows = value["n_rows"]
    maxDisplayItems = 50
    innerType = d.templateArgument(value.type, 0)
    p = gdb.Value(array.cast(innerType.pointer()))
    d.putItemCount(cols)
    d.putNumChild(cols)
    if d.isExpanded():
        numDisplayItems = min(maxDisplayItems, cols)
        with dumper.Children(d, numChild=cols,
               maxNumChild=numDisplayItems,
               childType="<column>",
               addrBase=p,
               addrStep=p.dereference().__sizeof__):
            for i in range(0, int(numDisplayItems)):
                with dumper.Children(d):
                    d.putItemCount(rows)
                    d.putNumChild(rows)
                    if d.isExpanded():
                        numDisplayItems = min(maxDisplayItems, rows)
                        with dumper.Children(d, numChild=rows,
                               maxNumChild=numDisplayItems,
                               childType=innerType,
                               addrBase=p,
                               addrStep=p.dereference().__sizeof__):
                            for j in range(0, int(numDisplayItems)):
                                d.putSubItem(j, p.dereference())
                                p += 1
```

And call it adding this line to your `~/.gdbinit`:

```
python exec(open('/<full_path>/debugHelpers.py').read())
```

or add it from your IDE; in QtCreator use Tools > Options > Debugger > GDB (tab) > Extra Debugging Helpers (near the bottom).

This particular script will return the matrix arranged by columns (natural memory arrangement in my architecture):

[image]

Sources: [Writing Debug Visualizers for GDB / QtCreator 2.8](http://plohrmann.blogspot.nl/2013/10/writing-debug-visualizers-for-gdb.html)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work in QtCreator 3.4.0. All Armadillo matrices get the value `<not accessible>`. I think it might be related to that my gdb is linked to Python 3. Do you have any suggestions? I'm adding the script using `python exec(open(filename).read())`, which is Python 3 compatible (`execfile` isn't).

Comment: I have finally gotten your script to work after some work. I ended up compiling the latest gdb (7.9.1), linking it to Python 2 instead of 3 using `./configure --prefix /usr/local/gdb-python2 --with-python`, and then using that gdb in QtCreator. I also had to add `import gdb` and `from dumper import *` to the top of your `debugHelpers.py`. But I would still love a version of the script that works with gdb and Python 3, since Python 3 seems to be the default now.

Comment: I now have it working with gdb linked to Python 3. First add `import gdb` and `import dumper`, then change the `Children()` calls to `dumper.Children()` and `range(0, numDisplayItems)` to `range(0, int(numDisplayItems))`. A complete script can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/YjbJr4wv) (link to pastebin).

Comment: Hi @FilipSund, excellent!. Before I accept your edit: I tried the script you propose with my Python2-enabled gdb, but I cannot import the 'dumper' module. Can you work around this with Python 2?, otherwise I will post two flavors of the script.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that error when running gdb in the terminal. But if you add the script to QtCreator using the "Extra Debugging Helpers" option it works as intended. To use it in gdb I think you have to add `/usr/share/qtcreator/debugger/` (or similarly) to the python path, f.ex. by adding `python sys.path.append("/usr/share/qtcreator/debugger/")` to .gdbinit, or running `interpreter-exec console "python sys.path.append('/usr/share/qtcreator/debugger/')"` in gdb before loading the script (this is what QtCreator does when you start the debugger). Or perhaps adding it in the script is easier!

Comment: I updated the answer including your changes, it is the only option that works for me now with QtCreator 3.4.1 and GDB 7.7.1. Python version is still 2.7.9.

Comment: After updating to QtCreator 4.2.0 I'm having some trouble with this debugging helper. I'm getting <not accessible> for all Armadillo matrices. Any ideas?