# Is there a way to print an Armadillo matrix or vector in Visual Studio Debug?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, armadillo

I'm wondering whether there is any method to show vector/matrix entries values in the debugging section on Visual Studio (in particular VS2012).

This question is very similar to the one posted in:

[Is there a way to print an Armadillo matrix in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499445/is-there-a-way-to-print-an-armadillo-matrix-in-gdb)

however I did not manage to figure out whether this approach also applies to VS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This `.natvis` XML code works fine in visual studio 2013. I added @Claes Rolen XML in visual studio 2013 and that dose not work fine for me.

The trick is to use `<IndexListItems>` to visualize armadillo matrix

declare and initialize code

```
mat tMat(3, 3);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        tMat(i, j) = i + j;
}
```

.Natvis File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010"> 


  <Type Name="arma::Col&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{{ Size = {n_elem} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <Item Name="[size]">n_elem</Item>
      <ArrayItems>
        <Size>n_elem </Size>
        <ValuePointer>mem</ValuePointer>
      </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>

  <Type Name="arma::Mat&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{{ {n_rows} x {n_cols} = {n_elem} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <IndexListItems>
        <Size>n_cols</Size>
        <ValueNode >
          mem+($i*n_rows),[n_rows]
        </ValueNode>
      </IndexListItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>



  <Type Name="arma::subview_col&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{{ {n_rows} }}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
      <ArrayItems>
        <Size>n_rows</Size>
        <ValuePointer>colmem</ValuePointer>
      </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>






</AutoVisualizer>
```

And Result image in debugger:

[image]

Comment: how can I cite this answer in my thesis??

Comment: just google [it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49760/citing-stack-overflow-discussions).

Comment: such a nice library like armadillo should contribute these tricks to documentations and forums in the term of debug helpers.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to confirm, have you developed the Natvis file, if not could you please provide the original source of this program. Seems like it is not developed by the original Armadillo developers Sanderson and Curtin, as I could not find the source??

Comment: I've developed this natvis file by reading Microsoft documentations, you may have a look if you want to get more out of it. This contribute was done by me.

Answer (score 3):

You may use visualizers in Visual Studio, don´t know from which version but in Visual Studio 2015 you may add a `.natvis` file to the project.

arma.natvis:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
    <Type Name="arma::Col&lt;*&gt;">
        <DisplayString>{{ Size = {n_elem} }}</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[size]">n_elem</Item>
            <ArrayItems>
              <Size>n_elem </Size>
              <ValuePointer>mem</ValuePointer>
            </ArrayItems>
        </Expand>
    </Type>
    <Type Name="arma::Mat&lt;*&gt;">
        <DisplayString>{{ Size = {n_rows} x {n_cols} }}</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[size]">n_elem</Item>
            <ArrayItems>
                <Direction>Backward</Direction>
                <Rank>2</Rank>
                <Size>$i==0 ? n_rows : n_cols</Size>
                <ValuePointer>mem</ValuePointer>
            </ArrayItems>
        </Expand>
    </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

This will show you readable data for the basic `ARMADILLO` types.

An example of how some types are showed:
[image]