# How to print armadillo matrix in gdb in complex cpp project?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, armadillo

I found a way to print armadillo matrix in gdb on  [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499445/is-there-a-way-to-print-an-armadillo-matrix-in-gdb) . However, what happens if

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>


template<class Matrix>
void print_matrix(Matrix matrix) {
matrix.print(std::cout);
}

//provide explicit instantiations of the template function for 
//every matrix type you use somewhere in your program.
template void print_matrix<arma::mat>(arma::mat matrix);
template void print_matrix<arma::cx_mat>(arma::cx_mat matrix);
```

is inside debug_armadillo.h file. How call function should be performed? I tried to type:

```
call 'debug_armadillo.h'::print_matrix<arma::Mat<float>>(C)
```

but the error I get is:

```
No symbol "print_matrix" in specified context.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How call function should be performed?

This call should work. Use Tab completion to autocomplete exact C++ type as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22766955/72178.

```
(gdb) call print_matrix<arma::Mat<float> >(C)
```

> No symbol "print_matrix" in specified context

Make sure that `print_matrix` function was actually generated in resulting binary. Try to `grep` demangled symbols, probably exact type differs a bit in template arguments from what you are trying to call:

```
nm -C your_binary | grep print_matrix
```

Comment: Thanks. However result of your last command is nothing. This probably means that print_matrix is not generated in binary and that's why I get error "No symbol "print_matrix" in specified context.". How can I fix this? The make files seemed fine.

Comment: Make sure that you are including `debug_armadillo.h` from somewhere. Or move `print_matrix` code to some cpp file.

Comment: That is why this is strange. `debug_armadillo.h` is included in makefile and everything seems to be nicely built. And I assume tab completion wouldn't work if that was not the case.

Comment: `debug_armadillo.h` should be also included from some cpp file with `#include` directive.

Comment: You are right I forgot this :( The  `print_matrix` is in binary, but now the error is `No symbol "print_matrix" in current context`

Comment: What about `call print_matrix<arma::Mat<float> >(C)` ? Note space between `>`.